# Make database operation and sending email a transaction

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have a website for booking hotels. After booking successfully, an email is gonna be sent to client. I did it as follow:

```
- Update table "booking"
- Check the result
   + If true, send email
   + Else return error
```

But what if the email isn't sent? That the DB was inserted but the email was not sent. It makes the booking operation isn't right. **How to make DB operation and sending email transaction**? Is there any easy way to do it? A and B must succeed or none of them.

Comment: Why would it not send the email?

Comment: You could use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and remove the record you just added if it fails ? or just insert after the email has been sent ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use database transactions, if you are using InnoDB:

Pseudo code:

```
Start DB transaction
Update table "booking"
Check the result
If true, send email
If email sends, commit your transaction
Else rollback your transaction, and return error
```

More info on transactions here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Do you mean use a stored procedure and do everything in it? The problem is I don't have permission on DB. I just use PHP and CodeIgniter. I write the code line by line in the PHP files.

Comment: @Emerald214, no I don't mean stored procedures, I mean ***database transactions***, check the link I gave you.

Comment: Perfect, additionally you will have to use the same MySQL connection object to rollback transaction and make sure that session wait_timout is set to a higher value greater than time required to send the email.

Comment: I don't know that email can be sent in TRANSACTION. I'll try it and reply later. :)

Comment: @Emerald214 you start your transaction with a query, then update your table with another query, send your email inside PHP, then if all goes well, commit your transaction with another query.

Comment: the commit can fail too

Answer (score 6):

A transaction in the strict sense of the world can't stretch something **inside** the DB as well as soemthing **outside** the DB. So we have to redefine "transaction" to be, that either all actions fail, or all succeed.

Here is an idea:

- Start DB transaction

  - Update table "booking"
  - Write an undo record into a table, with status "updated, not sent". This needs to have some ID, that can be used to undo the booking
- Commit DB transaction
- If this fails, bail out (no need to rollback)
- Send the email
- If this goes OK

  - Delete undo record
  - return "success"
- else

  - Use undo record to undo the booking
  - Delete undo record
  - return "error"

There are 2 things to understand:

- on an OS crash, Power out, etc. you have to manually check the undo table and compare it to the mailserver logs: The crash might have happend with the mail just failing, or with the mail being just sent, but not recorded
- **Most important**: I have yet to see a quick mechanism, that reliably tells, whether an email has been sent or not. **I mean really sent, not enqueed somewhere**

Comment: Excellent answer! One should not attempt to synchronize the database transaction on successfully sending email, this is going to cause locks and transaction timeouts as soon as you have a bit of load. A "two-phase" approach like proposed here is the way to go.

Comment: @Eugen Rieck Some systems can be configured to restart the app automatically after an OS crash, power out. Do you advice to disable auto-restart? Or, can we hook a script which will run before the system is restarted? Not sure if the script can parse mailserver logs reliably...

Answer (score 2):

> But what if the email isn't sent? That the DB was inserted but the email was not sent. It makes the booking operation isn't right. How to make DB operation and sending email transaction? Is there any easy way to do it? A and B must succeed or none of them.

Well, I'd say: start a transaction, input the data into the database and test for success. If successful, send an e-mail. If both the data-input and the sending of the e-mail were successful, commit the transaction. If either wasn't successful, roll back the transaction.

That said; there is no reliable way to determine whether or not an e-mail has successfully been delivered to an e-mailaddress. You can check the SMTP status code of the accepting server, but that doesn't guarantee that your e-mail isn't bounced later.

Comment: You can setup PHP to receive bounces, but likewise that wouldn't be a one step transaction, nor is it very simple.

Comment: @Petah True, you could do that, but it's much more complicated than that: your e-mail might be removed by a spam-filter, which means you'd get no bounce, while the user didn't read the e-mail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding additional column `status_flag DEFAULT 0` on main table

Steps:

```
1. Update table "booking" SET col1 = val1, status_flag = 1 WHERE tr_id = "abc"

2. Send Email

3. Update table "booking" SET status_flag = 2 WHERE tr_id = "abc"
```

So if you find any records in booking table having `status_flag` value as 1 then these are the records for which sending email might have been failed.

So you can either resend email from the same script or add another cron-job script to identify failed entries and take action accordingly.

Comment: But what if the `Update table_lock` query fails?

Comment: ya right got it, but this can be alternative additional fail-over method in cases when you can resend email.

Comment: Still in that case it would be better to just have an extra column on the main table.